# Copy CSS file content node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to copy the content of a CSS file using Node JS File system.
Here is my code :

```
var tpmFile = 'current.css';

var theme_file = FS.openSync("/tmp/"+tpmFile, "w");
var css_file = FS.readFileSync("/app/css/style1.css", "utf8");
FS.writeSync(theme_file, css_file);
FS.closeSync(theme_file);
```

`css_file` is always empty, why? Folder's links are good. 
Do I need to convert the css file?

Thanks.

Comment: Check what `FS.writeSync` returns ? Also check permissions on the file to be written on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably the filename path is wrong, try to use `__dirname` or path module.

also i recommend using async reads and writes instead of sync (unless this code runs in the boot-time of the program).

```
var css_file;
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/app/css/style1.css', 'utf-8',function(err, data) {
  if (err) return console.log(err), false;
  console.log(data)
  css_file = data;
});
```

If you log the response for us for `css_file`, we can help you more.

Comment: Thanks for your message. `css_file` returns `<buffer>` and if I set an encoding parameter (utf8), `css_file` is empty.

Comment: @PSport i replicated the code on my laptop (node v6) it worked without a problem. i did add utf aswell.